# High `WindowServer` Memory Usage M1 Mac OS X 11.3.1

Tags: macos, memory, apple-silicon

I purchased a new M1 Mac (8gb ram) in Febuary, and since then have had a problem with lagging due to high memory usage. Almost always half or more 4+gb is allocated to `WindowServer`.

The problem is exacerbated any time I plug in OR unplug my external monitor.

I've read [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/331964/windowserver-process-takes-a-lot-of-memory), which indicated that this was a bug back in OS X 10.x

Should I be worried about this specific computer being a lemon, or is this an OS X bug? It's quite annoying because it makes my computer essentially unusable for 3+ minutes every time I switch what display I am using.

[image: Activity Monitor]

Comment: Is chrome your browser using all the non window server memory? You’ve got some big leaks for sure.

Comment: All the browser memory items shown with the exception of `Google Chrome Helper (GPU)` and one of the `youtube` instances are safari.

Comment: As you memory pressure is now green the current state is probably OK and might just be caching - what matters would be when the memory pressure is red what does activity monitor show

Comment: In the screenshot it is all green, but quite frequently goes completely into the yellow and red. Again, particularly when I plug in or unplug an external monitor and stays this way for many minutes.

Comment: I have the exact same problem.

Comment: I have still not found a solution to this problem, unfortunately. Intend to take in to apple store.

Comment: It's an insult to customers if Apple is selling computers with their software draining half the memory!!! Either sell higher memory computers or fix the bug!